# Jersey Ajax POST error 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: jquery, json, rest, jaxb

My request doesn't get to the server... I've seen a lot of exemples but I couldn't find the error. I'm using jersey on GAE

This's my resource class that receives the request

```
@Path("/preMatricula")
public class PreMatriculaRS {

@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getPreMatricula(){
    return "Primeira requisicao...";
}

@POST
@Path("/save")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void savePreMatricula(Academico academico){
    //code goes here
}

}
```

That's my Pojo

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Academico {

private String nome;
private String cpf;
private String email;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}
public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

And this's my jquery function

```
(function($) {
    var path = "/rs";

    preMatricula = {};

    preMatricula.salvar = function(){
        var data = $('#myForm').serializeObject();
        var urlFor = path + "/preMatricula/save";
        $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              url: urlFor,
              data: JSON.stringify(data),
              dataType: 'json',
              contentType : "application/json",
              async : false

        });
    }
})(jQuery);$
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error 415 Unsupported Media Type: POST not reaching REST if JSON, but it does if XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773846/error-415-unsupported-media-type-post-not-reaching-rest-if-json-but-it-does-if)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789749/jersey-webservice-returns-a-415-when-executing-a-put-from-ext-ajax-request